# Calling .NET lib function from VC++

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am developing a application which requires to invoke a class function which is present within the .NET dll.

Is it possible to invoke this function from VC++

Consider following snippet of code.

```
Class A
{
  public string DoSomeTask()  
  {
     Some code
     return "return Value"
  }
}
```

The above class is present in a .NET dll

I want to invoke a method DoSomeTask() from VC++

Thanks in advance,

Amit Shah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/02/16/net-to-c-bridge.aspx) gives a good overview how this can be achieved (Reverse P/Invoke, COM, C++/CLI wrapper) and explains a pretty straightforward HowTo for C++/CLI wrapper (which I used).